# XBOX Controller setup in BGE not working

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I am trying to use the "joystick" sensor to use with a wired Xbox 360 controller.  I found a thing online that shows how to setup the buttons, triggers, and thumbsticks.  I want the character to move forward when the left joystick is UP.  It doesn't seem to be working.  I'm pretty sure I have the drivers and everything installed right because I have played games with it before.  I have the index as 0, axis, axis number 1, and a threshold of 6200, and Up Axis.  If you could find out what I am doing wrong that would be great.  Thanks![image]

Comment: 1. Check if the Motion Actuator works using a Keyboard Sensor. 2. Try out other axis and buttons. My experience is that Blender doesn't recognize my Xbox360 controller's axis the same way on Windows and Linux, even though other games get it right.

Comment: Ok I am not sure why but I downgraded until it worked, which was blender 2.71.

Comment: make sure you're using the left joystick, not the right one